# CSS: Input act as span (webkit)

Tags: css, input, webkit

It's possible an `input, select, textarea` act as `span`? My idea is create a print media CSS that visually transform all input of a form into a visual span to enable to print it without need convert all with javascript or create a specific page to print.

I need something like [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rWySb/1/).

It need be compatible only with webkit/chrome, so I can use the `-webkit-appearence` for instance. The main question is: it's possible with *only* CSS, or I need to use javascript?

Comment: What about about just styling them?, http://jsfiddle.net/ks89v/

Comment: Because it cut off if content is larger than input size and not break line when need.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the form elements to look like normal text, at least when they are being printed. This is indeed very much possible. You can add custom styling to your css, that applies only to printed media, by using a media-query `@media print`

The code would look something like this:

```
@media print {
     input, textarea, select {
        border: none;
        display: block;
        font-family: consolas, monotype;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background: transparent;
        -webkit-appearance:none;
    }
}
```

I have added the css to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rWySb/3/

Note that there will not be any visible changes, as this styling only applies to printed media, and not your screen. Use the print preview in your browser to see the effect. Or even easier, definitely during developing, is temporary changing the `print` to `screen` in the media query.

Note that I also added the default print styling I use in every project, which is actually 'borrowed' from HTML5 boilerplate. https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css
This is not required, but contains some nice tricks and ideas that might be useful for you since you are working with printed webpages atm...

Comment: Your solution is good, but it doesn't work if I have a multiline or cutted off content. For instance, if the value of textarea is bigger than the available space. Same to select or input options. I'm thinking that will be need I use javascript for this case.

Comment: It appears to be a problem with large content indeed. I tried playing around with `:after` and `attr(value)` but as the input has no real content (<input />) this doesn't seem to work eather. Pitty but I think js will be the only way for you... (Shouldn't be to hard though.)